# 3DTexture-based Volume Rendering

Tags: c++, directx, direct3d, directx-11, direct3d11

I've been trying to get a series of 2D images, all same in size and formatted as a raw data, loaded into a 3D texture and then render that 3D texture on the screen. As I'm still pretty new with DirectX, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Here's the relevant code:

```
// Open the image and copy its contents into a buffer

std::ifstream image("head256x256x109", std::ifstream::binary);

int size;
char* buffer;
if (image.is_open()) {
  image.seekg(0, image.end);
  size = image.tellg();
  image.seekg(0, image.beg);
  buffer = new char[size];
  image.read(buffer, size);
  image.close();
} else {
  return false;
}

// Convert the data to RGBA data
// Here we are simply putting the same value to R, G, B and A channels.

char* RGBABuffer = new char[ size*4 ];
for( int nIndx = 0; nIndx < size; ++nIndx )
{
    RGBABuffer[nIndx*4] = buffer[nIndx];
    RGBABuffer[nIndx*4+1] = buffer[nIndx];
    RGBABuffer[nIndx*4+2] = buffer[nIndx];
    RGBABuffer[nIndx*4+3] = buffer[nIndx];
}

// Create the texture

D3D11_TEXTURE3D_DESC texture_desc;
ZeroMemory(&texture_desc, sizeof(texture_desc));
texture_desc.Width = 256;
texture_desc.Height = 256;
texture_desc.Depth = 109;
texture_desc.MipLevels = 1;
texture_desc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT;
texture_desc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
texture_desc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE;

D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA image_data;
ZeroMemory(&image_data, sizeof(image_data));
image_data.pSysMem = RGBABuffer;
image_data.SysMemPitch = 256 * 4;
image_data.SysMemSlicePitch = 256 * 256 * 4;

d3dResult = d3dDevice_->CreateTexture3D(&texture_desc, &image_data, &texture_);

// Create a sampler

D3D11_SAMPLER_DESC colorMapDesc;
ZeroMemory( &colorMapDesc, sizeof( colorMapDesc ) );
colorMapDesc.AddressU = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_WRAP;
colorMapDesc.AddressV = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_WRAP;
colorMapDesc.AddressW = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_WRAP;
colorMapDesc.ComparisonFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_NEVER;
colorMapDesc.Filter = D3D11_FILTER_MIN_MAG_MIP_LINEAR;
colorMapDesc.MaxLOD = D3D11_FLOAT32_MAX;

d3dResult = d3dDevice_->CreateSamplerState( &colorMapDesc, &colorMapSampler_ );
```

Shader code is as simple as possible:

```
Texture3D colorMap_ : register( t0 );
SamplerState colorSampler_ : register( s0 );

struct VS_Input
{
  float4 pos  : POSITION;
  float4 tex0 : TEXCOORD0;
};

struct PS_Input
{
  float4 pos  : SV_POSITION;
  float4 tex0 : TEXCOORD0;
};

PS_Input VS_Main( VS_Input vertex )
{
  PS_Input vsOut = ( PS_Input )0;
  vsOut.pos = vertex.pos;
  vsOut.tex0 = vertex.tex0;

  return vsOut;
}

float4 PS_Main( PS_Input frag ) : SV_TARGET
{
  return colorMap_.Sample( colorSampler_, frag.tex0 );
}
```

Now I know that I would need to implement some sort of alpha blending for this to work properly, but I hoped I would at least get a first slice of the picture shown with this. However, all I get is the background color that I set in my Render function:

```
float clearColor[4] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
d3dContext_->ClearRenderTargetView( backBufferTarget_, clearColor );
```

Any help on what I've might be doing wrong as well as any further tips that I would need to do to achieve this goal (making a 3D texture out of a series of images and render it on screen) would be hugely helpful as there is very little documentation about this on the web.

Comment: You're not doing any error checking or handling.  Be sure to check the return values from any methods that return `HRESULT`s.  Also, be sure to use the [`D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476107(v=vs.85).aspx) flag on [`D3D11CreateDevice`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476082(v=vs.85).aspx) and look at the debug output.  I also don't see any calls to [`CreateShaderResourceView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476519(v=vs.85).aspx). Textures can only be accessed in shaders through "views".

Comment: @MooseBoys Thank you for your comment. I should've been more careful when I posted the _relevant_ code. I only posted the excerpts from the real code and I already do all the error checking and I use the debug flag, but I left out that code for brevity sake. I also create a resource view in my real code through which I access the texture and there aren't any errors in the debug output, it's just that nothing is shown on the screen except the background color. I'm really not sure what's the best way to go about figuring out what's wrong.

Comment: I would first try changing your clear color to magenta (`{1,0,1,1}`) and your pixel shader to `return float4(0,1,0,1); // green`.  If the window stays black, the problem is likely related to swap chain or presentation.  If the window is magenta, it's likely related to input assembler or vertex/index buffer data.  If the window shows some green, it's likely related to the volume texture, view, or binding setup.

Comment: This is piece
texture_desc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT;
says you have RGBA32F pixels which are 16 byte wide, but this piece
image_data.SysMemPitch = 256 * 4;
says that a slice should be 1/4 of what the format is supposed to be, so change either of them

Comment: @MooseBoys The window is magenta so it would seem that most likely the problem is related to IA or vertex/index buffer data. I don't really understand why there would be a problem as I simply took the example with a 3D cube that maps a 2D texture on all of its sides and I instead used the 3D coordinates for my texture in vertex data. Here's the relevant code for my vertex/index buffer creation: https://gist.github.com/2Pacalypse-/b1d2cd37ddb4d20cb5cc

Comment: @RelativeGames Thank you, I changed the format of the texture to DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UINT and I believe the sizes are now the same. However, I think I first need to resolve the above problem because even if I just write `return float4(0,1,0,1);` in my pixel shader, there's no green at all on the screen.

Comment: If you just return green and it doesn't show up then it's clear the problem is somewhere else, also make sure you pass valid texcoords for a 3D Texture, the parameter should be a float3 with the 0..1 range.

Comment: @RelativeGames I was sure that I passed the valid texcoords for a 3D texture, but now I'm doubting myself. Here's the relevant code for my vertex/index buffer creation, I would appreciate if you could take a look and see if you can spot some obvious mistake: https://gist.github.com/2Pacalypse-/b1d2cd37ddb4d20cb5cc